# MySQL Query - select all comments for a post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook

I have these tables:

tbl_posts:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date          | varchar(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status        | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| person_id     | int(10)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

tbl_comments:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |           
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment       | varchar(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_id       | int(10)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| person_id     | int(10)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and tbl_person which has person_id and some other fields...

i want to select all posts posted by a certain person and all comments for each of those posts (just like facebook)

i tried this query but it just bring me one comment for each post

```
select * from tbl_posts right join tbl_comments on tbl_posts.id = tbl_comments.post_id join tbl_person on tbl_person.id = tbl_posts.Person_id and tbl_comments.Person_id = 3 group by tbl_comments.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If your foreign keys are set up correctly, an `inner join` should be fine.  And, you don't need the `group by`:

```
select *
from tbl_posts join
     tbl_comments
     on tbl_posts.id = tbl_comments.post_id join
     tbl_person
     on tbl_comments.Person_id = 3;
```

Actually, I suspect the problem is `tbl_person.id = tbl_posts.Person_id`.  Your query was returning only people who commented on their own posts.

Answer (score 0):

When joining tables, you should always make sure there is a relationship between the tables you wish to join. In your case, this should give you all posts posted by a certain person and all comments for each of those posts:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_posts 
LEFT JOIN
tbl_comments ON tbl_posts.id = tbl_comments.post_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_person ON tbl_comments.Person_id = tbl_person.id;
```

So instead of doing

```
tbl_comments.Person_id = 3
```

You need to JOIN the tbl_comments and tbl_person tables like so:

```
tbl_comments.Person_id = tbl_person.id
```